# Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I got hit by this issue with setting up the webdrivers. I had to update my Chrome to 116.0.5845.97.
This is how my maven looks like :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Code for setting up the chrome Options and finally creating the webdriver:

```
if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.addArguments(new String[]{"--incognito"});
                chromeOptions.addArguments(new String[]{"window-size=1980,1080"});
                chromeOptions.addArguments(new String[]{"--remote-allow-origins=*"});
                this.driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 9006
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.97 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I have not been able to resolve this issue and hence reaching out to experts here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Selenium `v4.10.0` supports only up to `CDP 114`, which means if your browser version is `116`, then you need to upgrade selenium to `4.11.0`
   Update POM as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. If you are using selenium `v4.6.0` and above, then you don't need `WebDriverManager` any more. Selenium has an inbuilt tool now to handle drivers.
   Remove the below line from your code, you don't need it.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, I made the recommended changes but am now getting the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property`

Comment: Are you sure the selenium version is 4.11.0? Double check once. The fact that you are getting this error makes me think you are on lower version of selenium.

Comment: You are a legend.
After refreshing the pom.xml of my framework, I forgot to refresh the pom.xml of my project. 
It's fixed now and thanks a lot @Shawn(Heartbreak kid :) )

Answer (score 0):

Java: pom.xml webdrivermanager 5.4.1 and use the stable version https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
//not working with chrome version 116...(main version), so we are going to hard code for now;
//Next, we will pass it as variable with try catch statement to by bypass the hard coding after the fix

```
      //WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); 
      //hard code Chrome version
      WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("116.0.5845.96").setup();
      
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
      options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*"); 
      options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
      
      driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
```