# Chrome doesnt open during run the program

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

my dears,

can you please help to solve the problem? My browser no longer opens during the run. Thank you very much.

I got the following error since yesterday:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\AutoLog.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 116.0.5845.179 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006DA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x0066C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00575358]
    (No symbol) [0x005961AC]
    (No symbol) [0x00591EF3]
    (No symbol) [0x00590579]
    (No symbol) [0x005C0C55]
    (No symbol) [0x005C093C]
    (No symbol) [0x005BA536]
    (No symbol) [0x005982DC]
    (No symbol) [0x005993DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0093AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0097A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0097456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007651E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00675F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00672328]
    (No symbol) [0x0067240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00664FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x767E00C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77157B1E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77157AEE+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

my code look like this at the beginning:

```
import time
import pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

Comment: Please post the error message as well.

Comment: Did anything change since it last worked. Most notably, did you update your browser with a newer version?

Comment: Just upgrade your selenium version to the latest one which is `4.11.2`. Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76912466/7598774 Or this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76927754/7598774

Comment: Thanks a lot, now its working. I just updated selenium to the new version. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So all the lines of code look fine, but I think the error is that you have an updated version of chrome. The library wants the chrome version of 114 according to the error. You can check the version by typing chrome://settings/help on your web browser. If it is more than 114, then try writing (py -m pip uninstall whatever library you used) and then (py -m pip install whatever library you used) in the terminal without the brackets and with the names of libraries you used instead of whatever library you used one by one. (I am talking about windows. I don't know about Mac). We are just updating the libraries by deleting them and installing them again. I hope this helps...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).