# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 117.0.5938.89

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

I am trying to execute a Java selenium test.

Expected outcome: Browser session is started and test steps are performed.

Current behavior: Browser session is not started with error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 117.0.5938.89 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I am getting the following error after chrome got updated from 116 to 117 version:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 117.0.5938.89 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

In my pom.xml file I have:

> webdriver-manager 5.5.3

> selenium-java     4.12.1

Comment: didn't I see this question yesterday as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76927754/7598774

Comment: No it doesn't. I have those packages in my pom.xml and issue still exists.
When chrome was updated from 114 to 116 these packages updates fixed the issue but when chrome was updated from 116 to 117 issue appeared again

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, I used this link
([Chrome for Testing availability](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)) and checked the chromedriver according to my OS.
Do not forget to confirm and adjust if necessary the environment variables for chromedriver.

Chrome > Version 117.0.5938.132
ChromeDriver > [Download Link](https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/117.0.5938.92/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip)

I hope I have helped.