# Version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 121

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is a long trail for this type of issue in StackOverflow, but instead of keeping all of them in one batch, I was asked to create a new question so here goes.

This issue was initially reported when google pushed build 116. I am seeing it again now with chrome newly released version 121 (see image below).

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I updated pom to the latest recommended versions per mvnrepository (see image below)

I received this error (image below...) - Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

please advise.

Comment: Check this answer if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76927754/7598774

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your `WebDriverManager` to the latest version ([currently 5.6.4](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) - 5.4.1 is not high enough as 5.5.3 changes where the `ChromeDriver` repo is, and further releases add fixes to this).

Then before your next run, delete your cache to force the updated WDM to look for the correct ChromeDriver version - the simplest way to do this is to delete `resolution.properties` from your WDM directory.

Comment: This is the fix mentioned in GitHub for additional reference.
https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/1169#issuecomment-1809810393

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need webdrivermanager because Selenium as of Selenium v4.6+ has one built in. It's called [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager). My suggestion is to:

1. Write a batch file that looks for and deletes all instances of chromedriver on your computer
2. Remove webdrivermanager from your project

Now whenever you run scripts from your project, if the driver doesn't exist on your computer, Selenium Manager will find, download, and install the appropriate driver and use it in the run.

Answer (score 0):

If still facing issue with getting latest chromedriver then the below set of commands may be useful for you.
`SET workspace=<path where chromedriver to be downloaded>.. cd C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 for /f %%R in ('powershell -command "&{[System.IO.File]::Exists('C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')}"') do (set CHROME64BIT=%%R) if %CHROME64BIT%==True (for /f %%R in ('powershell -command "&{(Get-Item 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion.Substring(0, 3)}"') do (set ChromeVersion=%%R)) if %CHROME64BIT%==False(for /f %%R in ('powershell -command "&{(Get-Item 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion.Substring(0, 3)}"') do (set ChromeVersion=%%R)) set ChromeMajorVersion=https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_%ChromeVersion:~0,3% echo %ChromeMajorVersion% cd C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin for /f %%R in ('curl.exe %ChromeMajorVersion%') do (set CompactDriverVersion=%%R) if %CHROME64BIT%==True (curl.exe https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%CompactDriverVersion%/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip --output %workspace%\ChromeDriver.zip) if %CHROME64BIT%==False (curl.exe https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%CompactDriverVersion%/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip --output %workspace%\ChromeDriver.zip) cd C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 powershell.exe Expand-Archive -Path %workspace%\chromedriver.zip -DestinationPath "%workspace%" cd "%workspace%" del ChromeDriver.zip if %CHROME64BIT%==True (ECHO webdriver.chrome.driver= %workspace%\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe >> ChomeDriverPath.properties) if %CHROME64BIT%==False (ECHO webdriver.chrome.driver= %workspace%\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe >> ChomeDriverPath.properties)`