# Web Driver Manager Boni Garcia not working with the newest version of Chrome 121.0.6167.185

Tags: maven, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So recently Chrome released another update to 121 and ever since then I cannot run my tests on Selenium.
I updated my Selenium and BoniGarcia WebDriver Manager to latest but it is still not working. The error is the following

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 121.0.6167.185 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe 
Host info: host: 'CND2191P9W', ip: '192.168.0.17'
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [__remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\Users\IgorKorpak\IdeaPro...}}}]}]
```

I have had this this error before when Chrome updated to version 114 but I fixed it after updating Selenium to verion 4 but now it seems like it doesn't wanna start again. I have seen one of the issues posted here with same problem but the other person is using Gradel, I am using Maven build.

Tried updating dependencies
Invalidate Cache in IDE

My Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76927754/7598774

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WebDriverManager, make sure that version is at least 5.6.2 so that you will be able to pull the latest ChromeDriver version.

Please see link below:

https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/1169#issuecomment-1809810393

Updated with pom dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: my version before was 5.6.3 and since today I updated it to 5.6.4 which is the latest one

Comment: updated the answer with additional details @IgorKorpak

Comment: ok so I updated my dependencies as per your screenshot and now it is working but to be honest not sure what made it work, my dependencies were all latest...but either way, thank you. Would you be willing to explain the last screenshot tho

Comment: If you will be able to update your question and add your previous dependency, we might be able to figure it out. For the last screenshot, just sharing that WebDriverManager is able to download the latest ChromeDriver, Don't forget to mark answer/upvote. :)

Comment: so now I get 
java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden
and
WARNING: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:49748
two error I didn't have before... but everythings seems to be working fine, just annoying to have them

Answer (score 0):

If you use selenium above 4.6 and have that line of code - just remove it: `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your Selenium version is 4.11.0, please remove this line from your code:

`WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();`

It will work. This solution works for my project.